# Orthogonal verus Perpendicular Terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, education

This is a pedantic question about the use of the terms 'orthogonal' and 'perpendicular.' I think when people first hear the term 'orthogonal' they learn it to mean perpendicular, but in the linear algebraic sense, I believe it simply means that the inner product between two vectors is zero. This has no geometrical extension: just take a function space, for example.

But even if we are working in, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$, I could define an inner product that is not the standard one, such that two vectors that are $\it{orthogonal}$ are not $\it{perpendicular}$. So in this sense, perpendicularity is a purely geometrical adjective, referring to $\bf physical$ $90^{\circ}$ angles. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Both terms refer to an implicit choice of inner product, and are equivalent. "Orthogonal" just sounds cooler and more mature. (And this is a geometric notion; the inner product determines the geometry, in the sense of determining lengths of vectors and angles between them.)

Comment: But it has no geometric notion in terms of any abstract vector space, right? It only has a geometric notion in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 

Further, how do we distinguish between vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are ${\bf 90 degrees}$ apart, but which have nonzero inner product, due to how it was defined?

Comment: My point is that the inner product determines what it means for two vectors to be 90 degrees apart (it means they're orthogonal wrt the inner product). More generally if $a, b$ are two vectors in an inner product space then by definition the angle $\theta$ they're apart satisfies $\langle a, b \rangle = \| a \| \| b \| \cos \theta$.

Comment: @Johnver You should just expand your sense of geometry to encompass abstract inner product spaces.  The only difference I see between "orthogonal" and "perpendicular" is that I would say $0$ is orthogonal to every vector, but it is not meaningful to talk of it being ``perpendicular'' to another vector.

Comment: Yes, see $0$ is a ${\it great}$ example of what I'm trying to describe. Mathematically, it is orthogonal to any other vector. Physically, it makes no sense to say that it is perpendicular to or, ${\it at \: a \: right \: angle \: to}$ any other vector.

Comment: Orthogonal is a degree of abstraction away from perpendicular.  In Euclidean space, they are the same thing.  You have the idea, you can redefine the inner product and if the inner product is 0, then your vectors are orthogonal.  But there are other objects that are orthogonal, too.  In statistics orthogonal means independent of uncorrelated.  We have orthogonal functions.  i.e. $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos nx\cos mx dx = 0$ unless $m=n.$  So $\cos nx$ and $\cos mx$ are orthogonal with this inner product.  I have no geometric analogue to that one.

Comment: In the scientific framework, orthogonal should be the only word to be used, BUT in one case : in Euclidean 3D space where "perpendicular" should be used in the case of 2 planes whose normal vectors are orthogonal. Does this coincide with what you call the 90 degrees case ?

Comment: For an amusing use of the word "orthogonal" in a case presented to the United States Supreme Court, see the yellow box on page 174 in this document: http://linear.axler.net/InnerProduct.pdf

Comment: @DougM, funnily enough, objects that are uncorrelated can easily have nonzero inner product ($x=(2,1,2,1)'$ and $y=(1,0,1,2)'$: $\text{corr}=0$, $\text{inner product}=6$) and correlated objects can have zero inner product ($x=(1,0,1,0)'$ and $y=(0,-1,0,-1)'$: $\text{corr}=1$, $\text{inner product}=0$). So even though the terms *uncorrelated* and *orthogonal* are sometimes used interchangeably in statistics, I find it a little disturbing.

Comment: @RichardHardy the Euclidean inner product $\sum x_iy_i$ and statistical correlation $\sum (x_i-\bar x)(y_i - \bar y)$  one is adjusted for the central tendency and the other is not.  The rest of common calculations in statistics have a related calculation in linear algebra.  With such as standard deviation and Euclidean norm,  and correlation and cosine being very similar calculations.